# What can I do if I delete Xcode's Info.plist (not the apps plist)?

Tags: xcode, info.plist

Recently I am trying to study how to run the apps in debug mode in the real machine without code signing. This require me to change some setting in Xcode's plist (not the apps' plist). Before I do this, I use
> sudo cp Info.plist Info.plist.bk 

 to backup the Info.plist.

After I fail the test, I change it back by typing this command:
> sudo rm Info.plist
> sudo mv Info.plist.bk Info.plist
But there is a accident, I have typing mistake to the second command line like this...

> sudo rm Info.plist.bk Info.plist

Oh yea... I love to drink the red tea... Then I try to restart my Xcode, it cannot identify my Iphone and the Iphone Simulator...
What should I do to recover this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a backup of your Info.plist there ist probably no alternative to reinstalling XCode from scratch...